# How to set default input and output audio device sipeksdk?

Tags: c#, audio, sip, mixer

I am creating a softphone with sipekSdk and I need set default audio devices for my application and sdk.

I set the name of the audio device using:

```
pjsipStackProxy.Instance.setSoundDevice(string, string)
```

but this set does not work.

How can I do it?

Comment: What does setting it do? Throw an exception? Fail silently? Please provide more details as to what is not working.

Comment: no exception, when during the call, no sound. if I do not set the input and output of audio devices, the sound works fine.